# Some scenarios during edit of a question

Tags: discussion

During edit some question I am facing this type of situation:

After approving the edited question by the user I have seen the edited by user is someone else, but the changes is the same as what I have edited.

> [image: screen capture]

Comment: Could you try to rewrite your question in cleaner english? Also, please post example links of your situation, so we know what exactly we are talking about here.

Comment: I have added the screen shot for more clear. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Well, I happened to post an answer based on the same example. Please read it and think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, from questions like [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/130838/revisions) that your edits was bad. True, question got improved, but you:

- Failed at English grammar
- Used bad syntax (i.e. code syntax for list, instead of list syntax)

In your specific example:

[image: Non-code with code formatting]

Reviewer clicked "Approve and edit" and fixed your mistakes. He could just as well click "Reject and edit" - changes he did are of similar size to changes you did, and many people thinks it is OK to reject edit if it changed things to fix, but didn't really diminished amount of mistakes in question. So be happy reviewers found your edits on the positive side, and grateful they cleaned up the mess you did editing them. And please try to use proper syntax and proper grammar when editing.

Comment: Yes i got it actually that question was two times edited and i was doing lots of change that's why unable to got what change again done upon my change.

Comment: @Smalution if two users edit the question at the same time, higer-rep user gets "priority". That's why you should use preview extensively and think twice before you submit your edit. Especially when you are low-rep, at higher levels we don't need our edits to be reviewed and may hope to use 5 minutes grace period (our consecutive edits are shown as one). But by that time most of us already know how to not need these bonuses ;) That's the point of restrictions you are facing now.

Comment: in high-rep someone get any grace for edit?

Comment: @Smalution consecutive edits that does not require review are treated as one edit by the revision system. So if you will edit your own question twice in 5-minute period, you will see it looks like it was edited once. If you are high-rep, it applies to all posts, because you no longer need your edits to be reviewed.